# How to manage partitions after uninstalling windows

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, windows-10

After 2 weeks of using Ubuntu 16.04 I decided to uninstall Windows 10 and install it in Virtual-Box.So I formatted Windows partition to ext4 But right now I'm facing with some problems in managing my partitions!!
[image]

Now I have /dev/sda1 completely free and I want to use it as home directory for Ubuntu and install Windows 10 on VB in this new partition.
Is there any way??Or Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is on your ntfs partitions sd5 and sda6? and where is your home at the moment? on / (sda8)?

Comment: My musics,videos,etc are on sd5 and some of my working files are on sda6.Right now I don't have any separated home and it's on my root directory.

Comment: and you want to keep that on ntfs partitions?

Comment: Of course!I think there isn't any way to change the format without losing data!I really need them and I can't take backup of almost 300 gigabyte data .

Comment: Any help @ttoine ??

Comment: Set the mount point of sda1 to /home

Comment: How should I do that in GParted??Doesn't have any problem that my /home will be a primary and root is extended?

Comment: I would start with a fresh install.

Comment: You can backup your data. Furthermore, you should back up your data in case things go wrong.  You can buy an external USB hard drive that you simply plug into one of your USB ports.

Comment: Is there any way to choose sda1 as /home without a new installation @Steve R ?

Comment: The answer is yes, but it is complicated. Search for and read "Partitioning/Home/Moving - Official Ubuntu Documentation"  I also believe that it would not be recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a smallish hard disk, I wouldn't recommend a separate partition for /home, and especially just to run Virtualbox.

It would be more interesting to make /sda1 your primary and only Ubuntu partition. I believe that in gparted you can copy/paste entire partitions, so you could copy /sda8 and paste it into /sda1. *Once done, I don't know if you'd have to manually delete /sda8, or if gparted would take care of that.* Then use unallocated space where /sda8 was, to grow one/both of your ntfs partitions. You'd have to update your /etc/fstab and grub.

Something to think about. Comments from others about this idea? Cheers, Al

Comment: You mean I can copy everything from sda8 to sda1 and remove sda8??Doesn't it make problems for ubuntu??What should I do about fstab or grub since I'm completely new to them??And would you please explain more about your idea about virtualbox?What's you advice?What should I do?I will appreciate it if you explain the process completely.After all seems to be a good idea but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: I can't outline the **exact** process for you, because I've never used the copy/paste in gparted. I just know they exist, and can be used on partitions. Fstab would need to have the UUID for the boot drive updated to the different UUID from /sda1 using the `sudo blkid` command. Grub would need a `sudo update-grub`. Hopefully others will chime in to poo-poo the whole idea, or add more detail. Cheers, Al

Comment: okay,I'm just asking to get sure if it is **possible** or no?I will do it but just want to know if it may cause any problem!

Comment: Let others chime in about the idea. Because you're a beginner, it may be too much to take on, although it's fairly simple. I've just never done it myself, and since I can't sit in front of your machine to help, more research makes sense. Cheers, Al

Comment: Just one more question.When I click on my root partition all options are disabled.I think that's because of it's not unmounted.How should I do it?

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD. But again, I'd recommend a little more research before trying my idea. Cheers, Al

Comment: Of course, a simpler way would be just to install Ubuntu into /sda1 fresh, move any data from /sda8 to /sda1, then delete /sda8. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thank you @heynnema.although it drove me to grub rescue but at last I made it work correctly. So I'm accepting you answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Keeping your ntfs partitions

Since most of your personal data are already on ntfs partitions, I would not change that if you can not backup.

Instead, I would do a fresh installation of Ubuntu on sda1, keeping you date like this:

> - /dev/sda1  /
> - /dev/sda3  extended
>
>   - /dev/sda5 ntfs
>   - /dev/sda8 swap
>   - /dev/sda6 ntfs
>   - /dev/sda7 not used at all
> - /dev/sda2  not used at all

Doing a fresh install is fast if you have a usb3 pen drive with the Ubuntu installation iso on it.

### Clean install

If you can backup your data, I would do

> - /dev/sda1  extended
>
>   - /dev/sda2 swap  (16Gb)
>   - /dev/sda3 /     (50Gb)
>   - /dev/sda3 /home (the rest)

And then copy you data back in /home. This way, you will avoid issues with ownership and rights on you files.

### Other possibility

You can also edit the fstab file, but this is not something I would recommend to a beginner. More information here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: So you mean I'm forced to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: you can modify the fstab file. But you can broke your file system. Reinstalling Ubuntu is fast, you can do that in minutes. And you will benefit from a fresh install, a well sized Swap partition, ...